# Factorisation of $4x^4-4x^3+4x^2+2x+1$ with real coefficients

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I have used many mathematical trick to factorise this polynomial : $4x^4-4x^3+4x^2+2x+1$ with real coeffecients but i didn't succeed because as I see all it's root are complex , and  I want if there is any suitable method to factorise it ? and thanks in advanced .

**Note:** The motivation of this question is to compute some integral

Comment: If all the roots are complex, then for sure I wouldn't look into factorization of polynomials that have odd degree. But even degrees might be worth looking into. So if you have $(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f)$, the question then becomes: Are there suitable coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f$ that work?

Comment: yes and that is what i want

Answer (score 4):

Let $$  x = \frac{i t }{ \sqrt 2} $$

Your polynomial is now
$$  t^4 + i \sqrt 2 t^3 - 2 t^2 + i \sqrt 2 t + 1 $$
Divide by $t^2$  and then introduce $w = t + \frac{1}{t}$

dividing by $t^2$
$$ t^2 + i \sqrt 2 t - 2  +  \frac{i \sqrt 2}{t}  + \frac{1}{t^2}  $$
which is
$$  w^2 + i \sqrt 2 w - 4 $$

so the roots are
$$ w = \frac{- i \sqrt 2 \pm \sqrt{14}}{2}  $$
We get back to four roots in $t$ with two quadratics,
$$  t^2 +  \frac{ i \sqrt 2 \pm \sqrt{14}}{2} t + 1 = 0   $$

Finally we get four $x$ roots in conjugate pairs giving real quadratics as $(x - r)(x - \bar{r})$

Comment: Beautiful! But are there any methods of guessing how to obtain such symmetry?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke thank you. No method, really. First I tried $x=t/2$ I think. Then $x = i t/2$ to get the $\pm$ signs in a better pattern. Finally it seemed I needed $x = i t /  \sqrt 2.$ You could say it was trial and error.